# microsoft SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

While running a procedure it gives error like Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. But when I run same set of queries without any procedure it run fine. Can someone tell me what 's the problem

Comment: Without looking at the stored procedure, no.  Can you post it?

Comment: Most likely you either have a typo in your column definition or you're doing something like INSERT INTO t(a,b,c,d) values (1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: -1 for a totally meaningless subject

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that your stored procedure is asking for a certain set of parameters, but you are supplying a different set of arguments.  When you call the stored procedure, make sure any arguments given are correct for what is expected.

Either that or the stored procedure itself has an error trying to talk to a database table and getting the schema wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I just closed the microsoft SQL server Management studio and reopen it. Now same procedure is running fine. No idea what happened. Can someone give any clue.

Comment: @Abhishek pure guess, perhaps you were connected to a different database or something, and on re-opening you connected to the correct one.